# .eslintignore not working in sibling directory

Tags: gruntjs, eslint, grunt-eslint

I'm having trouble getting `grunt-eslint` to pick up an `.eslintignore` file.

My setup is rather atypical in that I'm running the task on files in sibling directories rather than in the working directory itself.

```
grunt.initConfig({
    eslint: {
       options: {
          configFile: '.eslintrc',
          extensions: ['.js', '.html', '.xhtml', '.htm']
     },
     one: ['../' + project],
     all: ['../*']
   },
});
```

My `.eslintignore`:

```
**/*.js
**/*.html
```

These patterns don't seem to match any files in the sibling directories. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is tantamount to how `minimatch` (used by `eslint`) resolves file paths preceeded by `**`. Indeed, `**` recursively traverses all subdirectories from the **working directory only**, which makes sense.

To properly match files in a sibling directory, it's a simple question of prepending the `.eslintignore` file paths with `../`, e.g.

```
../**/*.js
../**/*.html
```

Hope this helps!